# Entity Framework 5 - Migrations and creating table from entity

Tags: database-migration, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework 5 RC and i have some code that require a specific table on the database. The entity is already created using Code-First.

a) Is there a way to tell EF to create the table if its not already created in the database ? If yes.. how ? 
b) Also.. if the table already exist, can it handle entity changes such adding properties to the entity.. will it get reflected on the database ? (We still use the code-first approach here)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use code first migrations (either [automatic](http://msdn.com/data/jj554735) or [code based](http://msdn.com/data/jj591621)). If you are adding table to existing database create [initial migration](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/03/ef-4-3-migrations-and-existing-database/) first and than add your new entity. All links are for EF 4.3 but the usage is exactly the same in EF 5.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry i didn't answered fast. Ive just finished reading this article and this is really interesting.. If i understand correctly does this mean i don't need a db initializer ? it will generate the database the first time ?

Answer (score 0):

For reference for anyone else having this problem, I had the same problem and my solution is here
[Entity Framework: Generating specific table if doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539055/entity-framework-generating-specific-table-if-doesnt-exist/18856893#18856893)