# EF - Create missing SQL Table/Object from Entity Object

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework

Is there any function in the .NET Entity Framework, that can create missing SQL table. Or stored procedure or any other SQL Object?

Have do some research and did not found anything yet.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more ? What do you call a missing table or a missing object ? What's the context ? Code First, database First ?

Comment: I have a SQL database where I'm adding columns and tables and Foreign Key and after altering my database also update my EDMX classes to reflect database changes. Actually I'm keeping all those changes in a separate script to later update my customer’s databases. But this morning I thought that maybe the Entity Framework could do that for me! I mean update my customer’s database using the information in the EDMX classes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use code first migrations (either [automatic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj554735) or [code based](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj591621)). If you are adding table to existing database create [initial migration](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/03/ef-4-3-migrations-and-existing-database/) first and than add your new entity. All links are for EF 4.3 but the usage is exactly the same in EF 5.

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183595/entity-framework-5-migrations-and-creating-table-from-entity)